# how can I set instance in model when using form in django?

Tags: python, django

in model.py I have this code:

```
class wallet(models.Model):
    User = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    coin= models.PositiveIntegerField(default= 50000)
    password = models.CharField(blank=True , max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.wallet)
```

this is one-to-one relationship between User and wallet

in my form.py I Have this code :

```
class WalletForm(forms.ModelForm):
    User = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = wallet
        fields = (
            'User',
            'coin',
            'password'
        )
    def __init__(self , user , *args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['User'].widget.attrs['value'] = Profile.objects.get(pk = user.id)
        self.fields['User'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True


        self.fields['coin'].widget.attrs['value'] = 50000
        self.fields['coin'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True


        self.fields['password'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Wallet Password'
```

I am trying to make wallet for every user .. the question is :
how can I set User in wallet model to the already user who is logged in my site
when the form submitting ...

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilise the `form_valid` function in order to set the user before saving the model:

```py
class WalletForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = User.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        form.instance.save(commit=False)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Also, you should use attributes in lowercase, ie. change the following from

```py
class wallet(models.Model):
    User = ... # From this
    user = ... # To this
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can exclude the user field from your form
then in the view function do this:

```
form = SampleForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    new_obj = form.save(commit=False)
    new_obj.user = request.user
    new_obj.save()
```